# How can I manage files in two dimensions using Git?

Tags: git

## Problem

Here's what I mean by "two dimensions": normally Git is tracking changes to a collection of files over time (time = single dimension).

What I'd like to do is have a stream of "steps" that are represented discretely and those steps are also tracked over time.

I'm sure that's still confusing, so allow me to clarify further and provide the use case I am trying to solve for.

I want to track a coding tutorial as a Git repository, tracking multiple "versions" of the same code. The tutorial is cumulative, each step building on the code from the previous step.

So the tutorial might look like this:

**Step 1**

- creates file Foo

**Step 2**

- updates file Foo
- creates file Bar

**Step 3**

- updates file Bar

At any given moment I'd like to be able to do a checkout on an arbitrary "step" in the tutorial.

Now if the tutorial never changed, you could simply have each Step be a commit in series on the same branch, then jump back and forth between commits.

The problem is that the tutorial is complex and changes over time, and I'd want a bug fix to a file that is introduced in Step 2 to update the appropriate section of that file throughout all the steps after Step 2.

## Current Solution

Now I've already tried to solve my use case before posting a question on StackExchange, but it's a little cranky and I'm hoping for a better solution.

What I am currently doing is using a branch for each "step", so I have branches like this:

- master
- step-1
- step-2
- step-3
- etc

I have a script that I run whenever I update a branch that looks like this:

```
git checkout step-1 && git rebase master && git checkout step-2 && git rebase step-1 ...
```

You get the idea. I am using Git to track branches over time (first dimension) and using the script to control my second dimension (cascading changes across branches in a specific order).

The current problem is I'm hitting merge conflicts pretty often and I'm worried all the rebasing is going to make the repo hard to share publicly.

Is there a better / more elegant approach to solving this use case?

Comment: The obvious approach is the one you are already using, so, not going to suggest that. :-) But I will point out that Git doesn't actually keep track of *changes*. Git's commits are complete *snapshots*. Git fakes out the changes by computing them on demand: the change from parent to child is the result of `git diff parent child`. That is, Git has all the absolute files for each snapshot, and merely subtracts the two sets, to get the difference, once you ask for that. (Hence rebase does a lot of asking.)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question!

> The current problem is I'm hitting merge conflicts pretty often

There is no way around that. A tool does not have enough information to sort out how to do that automatically. If you go that route, try to keep the deltas very small, even if it means more commits.

Also, instead of using branches for that, you could build a program that knows how to build each step/document from a minimum set of information. For instance, i.e. a script that applies deltas/diffs or similar. Still, I don't think you will be able to give much extra heuristics/knowledge to avoid getting the same order of conflicts as with your solution; given the kind of text we are talking about (code, i.e. shuffles around a lot in a coding tutorial), but it might be a nice solution for other kinds of texts/projects.

Now, I think the best (and easiest) is to store the steps independently as different folders, but **keep a diff** of the steps recorded in your Git repo. Now, whenever you go to do a change, you can easily verify whether you have updated all the steps properly or not by inspecting the ***diff of the diffs***. Make a couple of small scripts to automate these comparisons/updates and there you go. Take a look at [`range-diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-range-diff) from the latest versions of Git to see what a *diff of diffs* looks like and how to color it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since it's code there's some other tooling attached to it that expects a certain folder structure, so while I like the idea of storing the steps in different folders I think that causes more trouble than it's worth. Looks like I'll be sticking with rebase. Any tips? Rebasing sometimes is fine and sometimes gets really unhappy, and when it gets unhappy you have to fix the same problem for each rebase, which might be 20x times doing the exact same merge fix as it cascades to each new branch.

Comment: You are welcome! Take a look at [`git-rerere`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere). I am not sure if it will like applying the resolution to different files (even if the conflict looks the same), but if it doesn't, I guess you could do extract the recorded resolution and then apply it manually.